# Bootstrap Dropdown issue ( When we fix the max-width to the button in the dropdown text-overflow issue)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

```
HTML :
<li class="dropdown display-bl">
     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle wrapping" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">CL</a><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu login">
   .....

CSS :
.wrapping {
    max-width: 150px;
    text-overflow: clip;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

here is the code above ! When the text limit crosses the 150 px the text starts to overflow clip as above css given.When the text-overflow happens it automatically hide the Dropdown icon also. But i need the dropdown icon to be visible even when the text overflows. Any help will be appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this code will work for you. Try to use the code which is given below.

*Happy Coding :-) ;-)*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
</style>
<body>
<div class="container">
<ul class="list-unstyled">
<li class="dropdown">
    <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown">CL
    <span class="caret"></span></a> <!--Drop Down List Menu Main title Here-->
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Login</a></li> <!--Add Your List Here-->
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply..but when the content is very lengthy i need to stop it to the max-width of 150px; So if i make the max-width then i need to use text-overflow so that the content will get overflowed. When i use the overflow concept then the dropdown icon is also getting disappeared.In this case too.

Comment: I have attached my code above in the problem statement. What i need is/. I need to have a fixed width dropdown button.So the content in the button which is (CL from my code),if it  become a lengthy word then i need to make sure the text should be overflowed.So i wrote the wrapping class above to overflow the text when it exceeds the button max-width,It is working perfectly fine for me but the issue is When the text get overflowed the caret class icon is also getting disappeared.I need the icon to be visible even when the text is getting overflowed is my issue, Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Your code is incomplete for me to solve your problem statement. Show me the full code so that I will help you. Thank you